# Transform the content of a DataFrame column from a BinaryType to a numpy array using readStream object (Spark Structured Streaming)

Tags: pyspark, pattern-matching, user-defined-functions, spark-structured-streaming, numpy-ndarray

My goal is to import an image using the `readStream.format("image").schema(imageSchema)` object, format and schema where imageSchema is:

```
imageSchema = StructType([StructField("image", StructType([
  StructField("origin", StringType()),
  StructField("height", IntegerType()),
  StructField("width", IntegerType()),
  StructField("nChannels", IntegerType()),
  StructField("mode", IntegerType()),
  StructField("data", BinaryType())
  ]))
])
```

My goal is to transform the last column *data* (which has a shape of 606300,1) into a numpy array of shape (430,470,3). Before using the readStream method, I tested with `read` and only 1 image -> I successed to do it with the following:

```
testIMage = spark.read.format("image").schema(imageSchema).load("/path/img").select("image.data").take(1)[0][0]

array = np.reshape(testImage, (430,470,3))
```

Regarging my previous code, I would like to know:

- Is it possible to use the equivalent of `.take(1)[0][0]` in order to have the whole values of each new image coming from my readStream?
- I know that Spark Structured Streaming works with DataFrame objects so I would have to transform my numpy array into a DataFrame after the transformation. For that I tried to create a UDF function but I don't understand what's wrong with it (see next code).

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> def to_np_array(x):    
...    return np.reshape(x, (430,470,3)).tolist()
... 
>>> spark_to_np_array = udf(to_np_array, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
>>> zz = image_df.withColumn('nparray', spark_to_np_array('data'))
>>> zz
DataFrame[data: binary, nparray: array<int>]
>>> zz.writeStream.format("console").start()
<pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery object at 0x7ff52e386e50>
-------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                data|             nparray|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[50 51 4F 4F 50 4...|[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...|
|[50 51 4F 4F 50 4...|[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...|
|[50 52 4C 50 52 4...|[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...|
|[50 52 4C 50 52 4...|[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...|
|[50 52 4C 50 52 4...|[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...|
........
+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Did anyone managed to do that kind of transformation?

The context is that I want to compare the RGB values of the image coming from my stream, let's say at the coordinates (128,377), to know if they are comprised in a defined treshold: I want to know if this pixel is grey or not (grey is approx. R:200,G:200,B:200). Using the numpy array after reshaping it, I just have to query `array[377][127]` to know its RGB values.